# How to check length of input equals to 10

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have to check the account value, that should always be in 10 number.So if it is not then we need to append 0 at beginning .I have achieved the XSLT in which I can append the 0.But how to check id the length is 10 or not? Please help.

I have tried below XSLT.
 when test="string-length(ACCOUNT) = 10" this is not working as expected.It seems it has returned ACCOUNT value.

Input:

```
       <JD>
  <Group xmlns="">
   <ITM xmlns="">
      <>
    <>   
    <ACCOUNT>1234567890</ACCOUNT>
     <>
     <>
   </ITM>
   </Group>
     <JD>
```

XSLT:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="JD/mo:Group/ITM">

       <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="string-length(ACCOUNT) = 10">

     <xsl:element name="GA">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNT" />
                                            </xsl:element>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:element name="GA">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(ACCOUNT,'0000000000')" />
                                            </xsl:element>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: It seems your code is working fine on checking `length`. Check if all XPATHs are correctly implemented.

Comment: Ya, so If I remove string-length(ACCOUNT) = 10" condition, then also else part will work like that (checking length and append 0)..am I right ?

Comment: Yes, `format-number(ACCOUNT,'0000000000')` itself is doing check and append thing.